# Div class only in one page via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a class:

```
.sample {
    background:url("../sample.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%!important;
    z-index:101
}
```

This is a mask and I want to use this class to be called in one page and not all the pages. How can i do?

Comment: may be use it only in the page you want..!

Comment: so, did you mean that you want insert this class, or let's say, mask layer, in to one specific page? or what's your point.. i don't get it.

Comment: @bitsMix yes, i want insert this class one spesific page but i don't have a .php file. I'm using Drupal. So, this work must via jQuery.

Comment: use inline css , so it reflects only in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<? if (eregi("yourpagename", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])){?>
<script>
$('#divid').addClass("sample");
</script>
<?}?>
```

Comment: What be my page name? Exam, index.html?

Comment: yup your name in which you want to add class

Comment: I added this code in my js file but don't working. Checked via Firebug, its problem: Invalid XML markup <? if (eregi("index.html", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])){?>

Answer (score 1):

Add a `title attribute` to div in which you want to add class like `title = "class_apply"`. and in other pages div add title like `title = "no_class"`

Now you have two options with  jquery .

1.Add class in all pages div with id and title.  and check for title attribute if title is no_class then remove class from those div.

```
var title = $('#divid').attr("title");
if(title == "no_class"){
  $('#divid').removeClass("divClass");
}
```

Or

2.make div in all pages with id and title.  and check for title attribute if title is class_apply then add class to that div.

```
var title = $('#divid').attr("title");
if(title == "class_apply"){
  $('#divid').addClass("divClass");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the css file using:

```
drupal_add_css ('myfile.css');
```

myfile.css:

```
.sample {
    background:url("../sample.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%!important;
    z-index:101
}
```

or

use inline css stlye to suit your purpose.